# Android - Populate a textview from a Spinner item

Tags: android, textview, spinner

I would like to have my application populate an empty textview with the value that a user selects from a spinner. Currently it seems to work, but it only populates the textview with what I'm guessing is the entire cursor: (android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@4120dd08).
Can someone help me figure out what the issue is? I can post more code if necessary.

```
 // Set spinner listener to populate the description field onclick.
    mContext = this;
    commonDescSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

            String stringItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            mDescriptionText.setText(stringItem);

        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 // Set spinner listener to populate the description field onclick. 
    mContext = this; 
    commonDescSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() { 
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){ 
              TextView objTextView = (TextView) commonDescSpin.getSelectedView();
            String stringItem = objTextView.getText().toString();
            mDescriptionText.setText(stringItem); 

        } 
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {} 
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The method toString() usually has other implementations relating to identifying object instances.  If you know that the item in the spinner is without a doubt a string, you could consider performing an explicit cast:

```
String stringItem = (String)(spinner1.getItemAtPosition(2));
textViewStatus.setText(stringItem);
```